# HIGH speed Level Shifting

Tags: npn, level-shifting

I was working on FPGA project that will be able to detect and timestamp input pulses from a series of detectors giving off a 20 ns pulse for each positive detection. Problem arises is two fold:

1. the FPGA I have to work with does not have a high speed transceiver, so I am stuck with using GPIO. Since I also using the same single GPIO to fabricate a BASE10-T ethernet TX line, I am unfortunately stuck at 2.5V TTL (JEDEC Standard No. 8-5A.01, www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/docs/JESD8-5A-01.pdf)
2. the detector are giving me a 5 V TTL signal. Hence I have to level shift it to 2.5 V, with special eye on the transmission time. SO i came up with this:

[image: shematics]

this is a barebone setup with a BFT25 NPN transistor rated at 2 GHz and a I_c,max of 6.5mA (www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BFT25_CNV.pdf).

Question is:
1. will this be fast enough? I probably will add a speedup capacitor, but I am unsure what the value should be, assuming I donot want a delay more than 1ns.

i did some math and right now I have settled with the following values for the resistor:
RB_0 = 95K ohm;
RE_0 = 3.3K ohm;
V_cc = 3.3 V.;
I_c(sat) = 1 mA;
target Vce = 0.8 V;
I_c (operation) = 0.75 mA.;
I_b = 19 micro A (hFE = 40 approx);
V_o = V_re0 = 2.55 V

I have been looking at NC7SZ125 also, but it has a delay of 3ns, and if i can help it, i rather use the NPN transistors just to avoid that delay. 
https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/NC/NC7SZ125.pdf

If you can, please recommend a value for the speedup cap, or maybe a little lecture on how to find it. :)

looking forward to your comments.

I understand the 95 kohm resistor will pose some problems, but, I can achieve the same results using R_e=1k and R_b=22K and V_Cc = 5v.

and if i using a different transistor (BFT540) with R_e=50 ohm and R_b=240 ohm.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a passive voltage divider with capacitive compensation?

You need to know the exact output level from your sensor.  You mention both 5V and TTL - these are not synonymous.  A TTL logic HI is defined as any voltage greater than 2.1V.  However, many modern devices use CMOS output stages and actually deliver a logic HI voltage approximately equal to their supply voltage.

When you know what your logic HI voltage is, then calculate the voltage divider ratio.  From that, you can choose your resistors.

You don't mention which FPGA family you are using, so I don't know what the input stages look like.  Usually, these are high impedance CMOS inputs - but not always.  You need to know what you are dealing with in order to pick resistor values.

Finally, add compensating capacitors across the resistors.  Basic schematic follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOjnDB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pick C1 & C2 to give you a flat frequency response.  I normally would use an accurate square wave and vary the value of either C1 or C2 to give you a flat top, especially at the leading edge.

Change the values of the components to suit your specific requirements.

Comment: thnx. its a DE2-115.

when i said 5V ttl, i meant, it gives 0 V for high and 5 volts for low. these are theoretical values. in practice these values differ from one detector to another. but yes

Comment: DE2-115 will take loads of inputs but i am using 2.5 V LVTTL

Comment: @RashedSarwar, FYI, that doesn't sound like TTL at all. A classic TTL gate, powered by 5 V, produces a typical high output level of only 2.5 - 3.5 V. This kind of subtlety is why it's important to keep track of the difference between TTL and CMOS logic.

Comment: @reid: tried it in lab, as i suspected, its not fast enough. i am going with http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/GTL2000.pdf instead.

cheers